# Can Monero recover from an inflation bug event?

Tags: monerod, cryptonote

Is this scenario likely?

1. An inflation bug is introduced by pushing malicious code / 51% attack on the network by a state level actor
2. Malicious party prints x amount of Monero and then randomly distributes them between Y number of addresses
3. Inflation bug is identified and patched by the community
4. Attacker slowly dumps newly minted fake Monero on the masses since nobody knows how many were printed <- assuming newly minted Monero stay on-ledger after patch (I am not sure if this is even possible)

Comment: It really depends on the details. But a 51% attack cannot do what you suggest, it'd have to be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

History shows that Monero community is very careful and alert. The key image malleability bug (which could have allowed double spending) [was fixed before anyone could exploit it](https://www.getmonero.org/2017/05/17/disclosure-of-a-major-bug-in-cryptonote-based-currencies.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Can Monero recover from an inflation bug event?

Yes.

> Is this scenario likely?

No.